# How do I register Broadcast receiver in service on Android?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to toast a message whenever SMS is received by using broadcast receiver on service. So, as long as the service is running on background, message has to be toasted when the phone receives SMS.

On Manifest,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Along with the permission above, I do ask run-time permission on my Activity which are shown below

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

and If the user clicks the button on Activity, the service starts and I tried to register broadcast receiver in onCreate() of the service class as the code below.

```
    public class MyService extends Service {

        private void showSuccess () {
    Toast.makeText(this, "broadcast received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}   

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            showSuccess();
            }
        public MyReceiver() {

       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCreate() has been executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //handler = new Handler(getApplication().getMainLooper());
        final IntentFilter it = new IntentFilter();
        it.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVER");
        mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, it);
    }
```

I tried keeping the broadcast receiver as a separated class, and as an inner class like above, but they both won't work. I am able to see the toast message "onCreate() has been executed", but I am not able to see "broadcast received".
I also did not forget to unregister when it onDestroy() is called.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you define your service and broadcast receiver in Manifest?

Comment: https://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62 try this example.

Comment: Yes, Fahad, when I kept the broadcast receiver class separated, I had
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
        </receiver>

in Manifest file

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
you are missing this permission.

Comment: I added it, but it wouldn't work

Answer (score 2):

Add Intent filter action in your receiver.Check the intent filter action you mentioned in onCreate() of your service.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**EDIT**

In your onCreate() method change line:

```
it.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVER");
```

to

```
it.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, accept the answer with green tick :)